# Can I get the calling instance from within a method via reflection/diagnostics?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a way via System.Reflection, System.Diagnostics or other to get a reference to the actual instance that is calling a static method without passing it in to the method itself?

For example, something along these lines

```
class A
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        StaticClass.ExecuteMethod();
    }
}

class B
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        SomeOtherClass.ExecuteMethod();
    }
}
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static void ExecuteMethod()
    {
        // Returns an instance of A if called from class A
        // or an instance of B if called from class B.
        object caller = getCallingInstance();
    }
}
```

I can get the type using [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.GetFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframes.aspx), but is there a way to get a reference to the actual instance?

I am aware of the issues with reflection and performance, as well as static to static calls, and that this is generally, perhaps even almost univerally, not the right way to approach this. Part of the reason of this question is I was curious if it was doable; we are currently passing the instance in.

```
ExecuteMethod(instance)
```

And I just wondered if this was possible and still being able to access the instance.

```
ExecuteMethod()
```

---

@Steve Cooper:
I hadn't considered extension methods. Some variation of that might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe you can. Even the StackTrace and StackFrame classes just give you naming information, not access to instances.

I'm not sure exactly why you'd want to do this, but know that even if you could do it it would likely be very slow.

A better solution would be to push the instance to a thread local context before calling ExecuteMethod that you can retrieve within it or just pass the instance.

Answer (score 10):

Consider making the method an extension method. Define it as:

```
public static StaticExecute(this object instance)
{
    // Reference to 'instance'
}
```

It is called like:

```
this.StaticExecute();
```

I can't think of a way to do what you want to do directly, but I can only suggest that if you find something, you watch out for static methods, which won't have one, and anonymous methods, which will have instances of auto-generated classes, which will be a little odd.

I do wonder whether you should just pass the invoking object in as a proper parameter. After all, a `static` is a hint that this method doesn't depend on anything other than its input parameters. Also note that this method may be a bitch to test, as any test code you write will not have the same invoking object as the running system.

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: This is actually passing the instance to the static method (which was asked not to in the question). It is just passing it in another variation of the syntax.

Comment: @StijnVanAntwerpen yeah, that's correct. But the original question is a poor question. If you want to use a variable, just pass it in -- don't use reflection or stack frames. This provides a syntactic approach to create similar-looking code, but the reality is, just don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just have ExecuteMethod take an object. Then you have the instance no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a static method calling your static method, there is no calling instance.

Find a different way to accomplish whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing something, here. The static method can be called from literally anywhere. There's no guarantee that a class A or class B instance will appear anywhere in the call stack.

There's got to be a better way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do.