# retrieving the reference to the calling class instance from a method in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario in C#

```
public class classA
{
public int fieldA = 1;

public classA()
{
    classB b=new classB();
    b.Execute();
}
}


public class classB
{
    public Execute() 
    {
        //I can get the type of classA using
        FieldInfo fi = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType
    }
}
```

The question is how do I get the reference of classA that invoked the Execute in the instance of classB?

I tried using reflection but could not find any way to do it.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get calling instance from within method via reflection/diagnostics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97193/can-i-get-calling-instance-from-within-method-via-reflection-diagnostics)

Comment: Is it an acceptable design that `classB` is provided a reference to `classA` in either its constructor or `Execute` method as a parameter?

Comment: the Execute method is invoked by a number of other objects and I do not have the option to modify it or overload it

Answer (score 3):

You can send a the reference of A to B in execute method like this:

```
b.Execute(this);
```

you can reach the object A by this way.

Answer (score 1):

**Change class B like this**

```
public class B
{
    public Execute(A aObj) 
    {
        //class A Object is available here


    }

}
```

**Change Class A like this**

```
public class A

{
   public A()
        {

            B b = new B();
            b.Execute(this);
        }
}
```